# Trying to add an attachment to an email from excel where only the first part of the file name is known

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro which I am using to attach an automatically generated file to an email on a daily basis.

The filename is required to be a certain format which includes the date and time, and as this is automatic, only the date will be known inherently (without manually checking the file).

- I am using `.Attachments.Add` and `format(date... etc.)` to get the second part of the file name.
- The first part is a number and a word which don't change
- but the third part (shown as "`*.csv`" below) is the bit that is causing the issue.

I have tried to substitute `*` like I saw on a forum but it where it seemed to work in that example it is not working for me. Am I missing something?

```
.Attachments.Add ("G:\AML, CFT & Sanctions\Sanctions\KYC6 Person & Organsation Reports\" & Format(Date, "yyyy") & "\" & Format(Date, "mmmm") & "\65436546_Test_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & "*.csv")
```

Comment: E-mail attachment? Is this really _Excel_? Looks like you're rather [invoking Outlook via COM object `Outlook.Application`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302602/sending-email-attachments-from-excel-via-vba).

Comment: you need to supply concrete file name. No wild cards.

Comment: Side note: invoking `Date` multiple times is unsafe if the script will even run around midnight. Call it once and save into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kostas suggested, you can find files by a glob with the [`Dir` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dir-function). Note that it only returns filename, without a path.

Do handle the case when nothing or more than one file matches the pattern. (My code produces an error in these cases; error codes are taken from http://www.halfile.com/vb.html .)

```
Dim date_ As Date, pattern, dir_, filename As String: date_ = Date

dir_ = "C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\test & test\" & _
       Format(date_, "yyyy\\mmmm\\")
pattern = "65436546_Test_" & Format(date_,"yyyymmdd") & "*.csv"

filename = Dir(dir_ & pattern)
If Len(filename) = 0 Then Error 53 'File not found
If Len(Dir()) <> 0 Then Error 58 'More than one matching file

<email>.Attachments.Add(dir_ & filename)
```

Comment: @andimac should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Build the file path first, test it and attach it if it's valid. As advised in comments, you need to supply a concrete file name, wildcards are not allowed.

```
Dim path_ As String, name_ As String, file_ As String

path_ = "C:\Some folder\"
name_ = "*.csv"

file_ = Dir(strPath & name_)

If Len(Dir(path_ & file_)) > 0 Then
    .Attachments.Add path_ & file_
End If
```

Comment: This is resulting in a file name with an asterisk, which makes sense if wildcards are not allowed here. If that is the case, is there a simple alternative?

Comment: No. Using wildcards, you have to get the concrete file path from `Dir()` and then attach the concrete path.